# How to convert Linux date to another date format

Tags: bash, shell-script, date

I am getting date in one of file in the format "Fri Feb 25 16:07:17 UTC 2022" Which I want to convert it to "2022-02-25 16:07:17".
However I am able to do it using Python but its being long process to call python from shell script and getting that variable back.

Just I am looking for simple option to convert "Fri Feb 25 16:07:17 UTC 2022" it to "2022-02-25 16:07:17" using bash shell script.

Comment: Thanks @Panki I have updated the question

Comment: To be pedantic, bash itself cannot do this. You have to some _some_ external command. `date` or `python` are both external tools.

Comment: thanks @glennjackman, I used the below provided answer by Panki, Its working fine for me. Actually i wanted to get rid of using Python inside the shell and it was being overhead just for date conversion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `date` for this task.

```
mydate="Fri Feb 25 16:07:17 UTC 2022"
date -u -d "$mydate" "+%F %T"
```

`-u` tells `date` to output the result in UTC. See `man date` for more formatting options.

Comment: Thanks its working perfectly .